# Google Maps through Java?

Tags: java, apache, google-maps

I'm using Java and want to open Google Maps in my default browser with a predefined start and destination. I know how to open the home of google maps in the browser but is there any easy (or any way at all) to have my program automatically input the start and ending addresses and then select the first choice?

Thanks!

Comment: didnt got u..??? plz clarify ur question

Comment: didnt get the question but since you mentioned java i am assuming you wanted some api. If so here it is http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_java.html

Comment: Just use a query string as suggested by Dan.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to http://maps.google.com
2. Enter an address and search
3. Click `get directions` and enter another address
4. Click `Link` at the top of the map
5. Look at the URL generated, see that it contains plain text start and end addresses, which you could build as a string in your program

Comment: See step 4. Clicking `Link` at the top of the map gives you a link to the map you're seeing. That link contains the start and destination addresses you typed, showing you the format for building your own links.